# ASUS M2N68 BEEP 1 long, 3 short, Tried everithing, works only with one video card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have the following configuration:

- ASUS M2N68 Rev.2
- AMD AM2 5400+
- 2x1 Gb Kingston DDR800
- GeForce 8400GS 256M/64B PCIx
- SL500-A PSU

The PC works like a charm for years until I accidentally pressed the reset button. It does not start and says no signal on the monitor. The computer does not post, but beeps long once, followed by three short beeps.

I suppose that is a graphics card failure. I am a PC technician, so I have some components at home. I tried it with another card (an older one with the same specs), and the PC starts up normally. I reinstalled the other card into the PC to be sure it is dead. I bought a new GeForce 210 Silent and installed it, but it does not start. The beep code is the same as before.

I tried another card from another PC, but it still doesn't boot.
After that, I tried all the cards in the other PC and all of them work perfect.

I replaced the RAM, PSU, and everything possible in the bad PC, but it only starts with the one Geforce card.

- GeForce 8400GS 256M/64B PCIx (old one what works for years on this PC)
- GeForce 6200LE 256M/64B PCIx (the one that works)
- GeForce 210 Silent 1G/64B PCIx (the new one)
- Radeon EAX300SE 128M/64B PCIx (from other PC)
- S3 Virage 4Mb (old PCI card)

Is there anything else that I can try to get the other cards to work?

Comment: "replaced RAM, PSU, everything possible"  Does "everything possible" include the motherboard?  If you replaced the PSU and the RAM, then it sounds like it's probably a failing motherboard.

Comment: Only the MB and CPU was not replaced. I don't have founds to buy a new set of MB+CPU+RAM and I don't found AM2+ MB in our stores. I don't understand why it starts with that card and didn't with the rest. Thanks!

Comment: p.s. Updated BIOS but no luck.